# c# mysql best way to upload a large data table to a mysql db table

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, large-data

I have a really large table with about a 1,000,000 rows of data in a c# datatable and I would like to upload that into a mysql db table. What is the best and fastest way to do this ?

Looping through the rows and uploading one row at a time looks to be the really bad performance wise and also throws a timeout exception at times.

I know that one of the solutions is to write it out to a file and read it from file using mysqlbulkloader. Is there any other way this could be done directly from the data table to the database ?

Comment: There is, of course, you could insert it, Im not sure if BulkInsert will work with MySQL but you could look into it. My suggestion though is that you do write it out to a file and bulkImport it. My own recent experience with this was that any form of insert from a list to the db (I tried inserting each line and BulkInsert using link2SQL) is going to be deadly slow. For over 2 million records BulkImport did the job hundreds of times faster.

Comment: after you try the answer below, which looks a lot like the 2nd method I tried, if it takes longer then a minute or 2, try adding a stored procedure that calls bulkimport directly from MySQL to load a tab delimited file that you've written out from a List. You will be pleasantly surprised I think. My experience was with SQL Server however so I'm not 100% sure how it will go.

Answer (score 1):

A non-generic solution exists in the form of building a SQL query using `StringBuilder`. I have used a solution like this for MSSQL 2008, so it may prove useful for you.

```
string _insertQuery(IEnumerable<Item> datatable) { 
  sb.Append("INSERT INTO table (coltext, colnum, coltextmore) VALUES "); 
  foreach (var i in datatable) { 
    sb.AppendFormat("('{0}', {1}, '{2}'),", 
      new object[] { i.ColText, i.ColNum, i.ColTextMore }); 
  }
  sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
  return sb.ToString();  
}
```

And you will (probably) need a way to page through the 1,000,000 rows:

```
var lst = new List<Item>(); 

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Count; i += 1000) { 
  _insertQuery(lst.RangeOf(i, 1000); 
}
```

`RangeOf()` is an `IList` extension I wrote that pages through the list:

```
public static IList<T> RangeOf<T>(this IList<T> src, int start, int length) { 
  var result = new List<T>(); 
  for (int i = start; i < start + length; i++) { 
    result.Add(src[i]); 
  }
  return result; 
}
```